# Keep query string in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a list of entities displayed on a page. In addition to that I have a form for entity filtration and a couple of quick links, like "hidden" and "shown" entities.

The "hidden" link's url is mysite.com/entities?hidden=1, the "shown" mysite.com/entities?hidden=0. So I pass hidden param in order to filter entities.

On the other hand I have a separate form which is placed somewhere on the page (I dont want to convert hidden/shown links to checkboxes and insert them into the form) which is used to filter entities in some other ways, like select entity category, or search by entity name.

I want to implement next logic: I click on the hidden link and got list of all hidden entities (mysite.com/entities?hidden=1). Then I use my form and filter entities but the "hidden" param disappears. In the form action I return `View::make`.

`withInput` doesn't fit because it's used in Redirect, not View class.

On of the possible solutions is to add hidden input which keeps the value

```
@if (Input::has('hidden'))
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="{{ Input::get('hidden') }}" />
@endif
```

Something like that. But is there any other solution? What if I have a lot of query params and I want to keep them.

Comment: use form method to GET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your form is sent as `POST`, so in order to post to the exact url you have now, you need this:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => Request::fullUrl(), ...]) }}
```

This will keep your query string in the url, so you will `POST` to eg.

```
domain.com/entities?hidden=0
```

**EDIT**

If you want to rely on `action` rather than current url, then do this instead:

```
{{ Form::open([
    'url' => action('PageController@showAdminMaterials', ['hidden' => $hiddenValue]),
     ...
]) }}
```

Mind that if referenced action accepts any parameters, then you need to specify them first, then add `hidden` that will become a query string param.

Comment: Actually my form is GET, but doesn't matter. Well, Request::fullUrl() seems to work fine, the only thing that confuses me is that I use it like  {{ Form::open(['action' => 'PageController@showAdminMaterials', ... So I use 'action' instead of url and I'm kind of sure that I'll send the request to the action that I need :)

Comment: And what is $hiddenValue here? Input::get('hidden')?

Comment: Yes, it might be that, or anything depending on your logic.